# Is there a significant performance impact when using function to cast variable in ng-template?

Tags: angular, typescript

When using `<ng-template let-varnme>`, `varname` is untyped. To overcome this, I am using identity function to typecast that variable .

```
<ng-template let-v>
   <span>{{cast(v).prop1}}</span>
   <span>{{cast(v).prop2}}</span>
   <span>....</span>
</ng-template>

cast(v:any){
   return v as MyType;
}
```

this obviously creates technically unwanted methods calls. Now my question is, is there a significant performance impact because of such approach? Maybe compiler is smart enough to actually inline that method.

Comment: I'd willing to bet that V8 engine will inline it. TypeScript compiler will not inline it

Comment: If you wanted to reduce the performance impact, you could use a `pipe` instead of a `function`.

Comment: Using pipe will be even more cumbersome - in context of template readability. I want that cast only to typehint the IDE. I am asking here, if implact is neglectable or not - because if not, I will simply remove cast function and live with false errors in the IDE ;)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling methods from the template as long as the time complexity of the method is reasonable. Any method with linear time complexity or better that is run from the template is usually fine. this is the comment from angular issue repo check this:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39634